# Why htaccess isn't working with pretty links

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu

Here's my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /go/redirect.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

This file is located at `http://example.com/go/.htaccess`

It is working correctly when people visit this link:

```
http://example.com/go/test
```

But not when it has a trailing slash like this:

```
http://example.com/go/test/
```

When the trailing slash exists, they are being redirected here for some reason:

```
http://example.com/test
```

How can I make this work with and without trailing slashes at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /go/redirect.php?slug=$1 [L]
```